# Remove view on click of button

Tags: ios, swift

I am using following code to load my table using collection.

```
self.window = UIWindow(frame: CGRect(x:40, y:120, width:self.view.bounds.width-100, height:self.view.bounds.height-200))
self.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

let mainController : CollectionViewController = CollectionViewController(nibName: "CollectionViewController", bundle: nil)
myController.TableHeaderArray = TableHeaders
let ApiResponse = self.dataTableViewdictParams(apiUrl)
 myController.UMIDDataArray = ApiResponse[0] as! NSMutableArray
myController.TableDataArray = ApiResponse[1] as! NSMutableArray
self.window!.rootViewController = myController
self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

I want to remove this table on button click and load another view. On button click another view gets loaded but I am unable to remove this table UIWindowView. How can I remove this?

Edit:

Added code which I tried:

```
function loadanotherView()
{
/// I tried these three codes but none worked for me
self.window?.removeFromSuperview() // code 1
self.window?.rootViewController?.removeFromParentViewController() // code 1
self.window?.hidden = true // code 2

let frame = CGRect(x:0, y:-20, width:self.view.bounds.width, height:self.view.bounds.width)
WView.frame=frame
let url = NSURL(string:"urlForTheWebView")
let req = NSURLRequest(URL:url!)
self.webView!.loadRequest(req)
self.view.addSubview(WView)

}
```

Comment: update your question with your remove button click method

Comment: added button click method

Comment: `tableView.dismissViewController()`

Comment: where is code that you remove tableview or hide tableview ?

Comment: Why are you messing around with the window? Look into using a navigation controller or something like that.

Comment: tableView.dismissViewController - is not a valid method.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use

```
self.window!.rootViewController = myController
```

Use This

```
self.window?.addSubview(myController.view)
```

And instead of using

```
self.window?.removeFromSuperview() // code 1
self.window?.rootViewController?.removeFromParentViewController() // code 1
self.window?.hidden = true // code 2
```

Use This,

```
myController.view.removeFromSuperview() // If Button on the another viewcontroller
```

or

```
self.view.removeFromSuperview() // If Button on the myController
```

Because if you make myController as root, it cannot be removed from superView. So add this as subview.

Comment: When I use - self.window?.addSubview(myController.view), it gives me error.

Comment: It says - UICollectionView received layout attributes for a cell with an index path that does not exist: <NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016>

Comment: 1st tell me what is myController and  mainViewController?